# grep is unable to find all pattern matching "\[\[\[\["

Tags: grep

I am having problems with using grep along with a pipe. The scenario is as follows:
I am running a python script that outputs (using print) to the screen debug messages. I use `./prog | grep "\[\[\[\["` to catch the strings with "[[[[" in them. It returns few matching results but not others (Another observation: results found by grep come before the results not found by grep in the file). I have ran the `./prog` without pipe and grep and it outputs all the strings with "[[[[" pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the left square bracket is a special character in regular expressions.  "grep" is not just a string matcher.  Regular expressions are an involved language that let you describe patterns of text.  Grep is trying to interpret `[[[[` as a regular expression, not just a string.

As your question subject suggests, you can usually escape special characters with a backslash.  So the following might work:

```
./prog | grep '\[\[\[\['
```

You can also "escape" square brackets by putting them *inside* square brackets.  Thus, `[[][[][[][[]` or `[[]{4}` if your version of grep handles it.

You also need to determine whether your program, `./prog`, is sending output to "standard output" or "standard error".  You can put all your stderr through the pipe with:

```
./proc 2>&1 | egrep '[[]{4}'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf '[[[[\n[[[\n[[[[\n[[[[[\n[[\n' | grep '\[\[\[\['
[[[[
[[[[
[[[[[
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf '[[[[\n[[[\n[[[[\n[[[[[\n[[\n' | egrep '[[]{4}'
[[[[
[[[[
[[[[[
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Obviously, my results do not match yours.  If you can provide more details as to the data you're processing, it will be helpful in trying to duplicate your results.

Comment: Ghoti, thanks for your reply. I didn't mention earlier but I am using escape sequences for the match pattern (just as you described as the first option). But the problem is that I get the first two statements printed to the screen and not the last two, though they follow the same pattern.

Comment: Furthermore, since I am just using 'print' function for printing them to screen, it hasn't anything to do with stderr. Anyway, I have tried it that way as well and it didn't work out. Any other thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user1126425 - the answer I've provided is the best I can come up with given the amount of detail in your question.  If you can update your question with example data so that your results can be duplicated, then I may be able to figure out what problem you're having.  As it stands, this is as far as I can go.

Answer (score 2):

Error messages are usually sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`; your pipe is filtering `stdout`.  (Your "another observation" hints at this.)  You can redirect `stderr` along with `stdout` to the pipe:

```
./prog 2>&1 | grep '\[\[\[\['
```

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, but when I say that I am using 'print' to print the messages, I assumed that all of them would go to stdout. Anyway, I have tried your suggestion as well, but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: You may need to update your question with more details, then.  Also follow the markup help link when you do so, so your examples don't get misinterpreted as HTML.